# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile while giving webdriver-manager start

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, gulp, protractor, selenium-server

When we tried to start the selenium server we are getting this error. It seems the latest selenium server standalone version is `3.7.1`. When we updated using webdriver-manager update command it is downloading the version `3.8.0` and when we give the command webdriver-manager start it is throwing the error as

> **Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile**.

Please see the screenshot attached.

[webdriver-manager start error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTMeU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workaround to bring the webdriver-manager version back to 3.7.1 according to this ticket:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5142

1. Update webdriver-manager to 3.7.1

   `webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone=3.7.1`
2. Rename `selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar` to `selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar`. By default this file is in the `%YourUserDirectory%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium` directory.

Answer (score 0):

There were issue with 3.8.0.jar. They have updated it. Please check the following link: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5142

You may need to update it again.

```
webdriver-manager update
```